# javascript server wont validate from my vb.net front end httpwebrequest

Tags: javascript, node.js, vb.net, mongodb, express

well I have developed a web service app.js that handles some products in a mongodb database, everthing seems to work fine from POSTMAN, i can do full CRUD (GET, POST, UPDATE, DELETE) and with my vb.net app i can do GET but POST wont work no matter what, need some help here.

this is my model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Plato Schema
var platoSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    nombre_plato:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    categoria_plato:{
        type: String,

    },
    sub_categoria_plato:{
        type: String,

    },
    descripcion:{
        type: String,

    },
    fecha_creacion:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    precio_plato:{
        type: Number,

    },
    foto_plato:{
        type: String,

    },
    estado:{
        type: String,

    },
    estado_contorno:{
        type: String,

    },
    contorno:{
        type: String,

    },

});

var Plato = module.exports = mongoose.model('Plato', platoSchema);

module.exports.addPlato = function(plato, callback){
    Plato.create(plato, callback);
}
```

and this my server module

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.json());


Plato = require('./models/plato');
//Connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://MYLANIP:PORT/DATABASE');

var db = mongoose.connection;

//metodo POST
app.post('/api/platos', function(req, res){
    var plato = req.body;
    Plato.addPlato(plato, function(err, plato){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(plato);
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Running on port 3000');
```

here is the vb.net POST method

```
 Dim HttpWebRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://MYSERVERADDRESS/api/platos")
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
        HttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
        Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
        Dim bytejson As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(jsonString)

        HttpWebRequest.Method = "POST"



        Dim StreamWriter As Stream = HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream


        StreamWriter.Write(bytejson, 0, bytejson.Length)


        Dim httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
        Dim streamReader = New StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())

        RichTextBox1.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
```

the vb.net gets me an error 407 as response from server, and the server crashes with events.js:160 validationerror: Plato validation failed.

i understand that there is some kind of problem when the server tries to get the data from vb.net and then crashes but

IF i do the GET POST DELETE UPDATE from chrome POSTMAN i get it all working perfectly as i said, also i can do GET from the vb.net app but i CANT do POST, i have tried everything and it refuses to work. I MUST say that if i try the vb.net server with a TEST server like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
it works just perfect too so in conclusion:

POSTMAN-> POST my server.js all good
my vb.net app POST->Json test server all good

but my app vb.net POST -> my server.js nothing.

any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: got an update, I have reduced the data to send ONLY the item name and changed the field from required to none and AT LEAST im getting a response back from the server, it gives me the item id thats autogenerated in the mongodb database {"__v":0,"_id":"587ea609951eeb16a0dec713"} BUT it does not registers the name.. again, with postman doing the same it DOES register the name, which makes me think that something is wrong with encoding in vb.net or the json parsing.. im usng the newtonsoft library to parse the json and again, the TEST server does submit the data im sending from vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well seems like I managed to sort it out.. all the problem was something out of my knowledge like this

```
var platoSchema = mongoose.Schema({



 nombre_plato:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    categoria_plato:{
        type: String,

    },
    sub_categoria_plato:{
        type: String,

    },
    descripcion:{
        type: String,
```

that is part of my mongoose schema and my class in vb.net is

```
Private _nombre_plato As String
Private _categoria_plato As String
Private _sub_categoria_plato As String
Private _descripcion As String
Private _fecha_creacion As Date
Private _precio_plato As Double
Private _foto_plato As String
Private _estado As String
Private _estado_contorno As String
Private _contorno As String
```

my mistake or lack of knowledge was that when I refactored that automatically generated this

```
Public Property Nombre_plato As String
        Get
            Return _nombre_plato
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _nombre_plato = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Categoria_plato As String
        Get
            Return _categoria_plato
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _categoria_plato = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Sub_categoria_plato As String
        Get
            Return _sub_categoria_plato
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _sub_categoria_plato = value
        End Set
    End Property


etc 

etc

etc
```

as you can see acces to the properties of my class autogenerated by vb.net , changed MY lowercase names to the same names BUT wit capital first letter and so it didnt match with mongoose schema.. man i almost went crazy with this...

well hope this can help someone out there too.